# Counting monomials and the Catalan numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, permutations, enumerative-combinatorics, catalan-numbers

Given a multi-variable polynomial $F$, denote the number of monomials by $N(F)$. Take for instance, \begin{align*}N(x(x+y)+(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2)=N(x^2+5xy)&=2 \qquad \text{and} \\
N((x+z)(x+y)^2)=N(x^3 + 2x^2y + x^2z + xy^2 + 2xyz + y^2z)&=6.\end{align*}
Denote the symmetric group on $n$ letters $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ by $\mathfrak{S}_n$. Define the action of $\mathfrak{S}_n$ on a function $F(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ in a natural way: given $w\in\mathfrak{S}_n$, then $w\cdot F(x_1,\dots,x_n)=F(x_{w(1)},\dots,x_{w(n)})$. Introduce the (multi-variable) rational functions
$$G(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z})=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{x_1z_1+x_2z_2+\cdots+x_kz_k}{x_k-x_{k+1}}.$$

Assuming that the symmetric groups act only on the $x$-variables, let's compute the polynomial
$$G_{\mathfrak{S}_{n+1}}=\sum_{w\in\frak{S}_{n+1}}w\cdot G.$$
I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Let $C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$ be the Catalan numbers. Is there a combinatorial proof that $N(G_{\mathfrak{S}_{n+1}})=C_n$?

Comment: Are you sure the $G(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z})$ are polynomials (as opposed to rational functionals)? I guess the point is that after symmetrization the $G_{\mathfrak{S}_{n+1}}$ become polynomials...

Comment: Edited. Thank you.

Comment: I checked findstat for the distribution of coefficients, to no avail :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any monomial $P:=\prod x_i^{c_i}$ of degree $\sum c_i=n$ maps to a non-zero constant after symmetrization
$$
P\to \Phi(P):=G_{\mathfrak{S}_{n+1}}\frac{P}{(x_1-x_2)(x_2-x_3)\ldots (x_n-x_{n+1})}.
$$
Indeed, $\Phi(P)$ is a constant by a degree consideration, to prove that this constant is non-zero you may use, for example, Theorem 2 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.07136.pdf).

Thus any monomial $\prod (x_iz_i)^{c_i}$ maps to a non-zero constant times $\prod z_i^{c_i}$.

Thus, you simply count the number of monomials which may arise, when you multiply the linear forms $\prod_{k=1}^n(x_1z_1+x_2z_2+\cdots+x_kz_k)$. The only condition is that $c_1+\ldots+c_i\geqslant i$ for all $i$. Such sequences are indeed enumerated by Catalan numbers, a bijection with lattice paths below diagonal is straightforward.

Comment: This is now http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St001786

Comment: Does your Theorem yield a direct interpretation of the coefficients?  Is it true that the coefficient equals 1 if and only if the path is a bounce path?

Comment: @MartinRubey the coefficient equals (upto sign) to the number of enumerations of  $n+1$ vertices of the path which satisfy $n$ inequalities which in turn correspond to the $n$ edges. The inequality $\pi(x)<\pi(y)$ for an edge $xy$ corresponds to our monomial $C$ being $y$-biased in the following sense: remove the edge $xy$, let $k$ denote the number of vertices in the piece containing $y$; then the total degree of $C$ in these $k$ variables is at least $k$. So, the number of monomials with coefficient $\pm 1$ (happens when all inequalities have the same direction) is twice Catalan number.

Comment: That's strange, possibly I have a bug in my code, but my coefficients are all positive.

Comment: @MartinRubey this is quite possible, I simply did not care about the sign writing my comment

Comment: (if you do not consider monomials which include $z_{n+1}$, then yes, otherwise this depends on parity of $n$, I think)

Comment: Well, also the number of monomials with coefficient 1 in my implementation is $2^n$, not Catalan.

Comment: hm... to be sure, do you consider all monomials, or all monomials without $z_{n+1}$, or all monomials which may occur in expanding these brackets?

Comment: I think I am using the definition of @T.Amdeberhan.  For example, if $n=1$ I have $G = \frac{x_1 z_1}{x_1 - x_2}$ and therefore $G_{\mathfrak S_2} = z_1$.  So, I have $n+1$ variables in the $x$-alphabet and $n$ variables in the $z$-alphabet.  $G_{\mathfrak S_3} = z_1^2 + z_1 z_2$, $G_{\mathfrak S_4} = z_1^3 + 2*z_1^2 z_2 + z_1 z_2^2 + z_1^2 z_3 + z_1 z_2 z_3$.  In particular, the number of monomials with coefficient 1 is $1, 2, 4, \dots$.

Comment: @MartinRubey ah, I see. My theorem yields the formula $G_{\mathfrak S_{n+1}}=z_1(z_1+z_2)(z_1+z_2+z_3)\cdots (z_1+\ldots+z_n)$, is it enough for your observations?

Comment: Oh, I feel silly now!  Thank you!